# Letsencrypt Renewal + Nginx + owncloud config = failed because of regular expression

Tags: regex, nginx, owncloud, lets-encrypt, nginx-location

I am running an owncloud-server with ngnix on Debian 8.
I use a ssl-certificate for that domain from letsencrypt.

Now i want to use an autorenewal-script, to run periodically and renew my certs. This works with all domains, except the owncloud.

Actually there is one location block in the nginx-owncloud-config, that prevents letsencrypt from enter the subfolder *domain.org/.well-known/acme-challenge*:

```
location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
  deny all;
}
```

By god, i am no expert in regular expressions and have no clue, how to solve this (and what this expression actually means).

Below that Block i included a location block for the letsecrypt-renewal:

```
# Letsencrypt auto-renewal
location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
    default_type text/plain;
    root /var/www/;
    try_files $uri /$1;
}
```

I think I tried something like:

```
location ~ ^/(?:\.(?!well-known/acme-challenge)|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
  deny all;
}
```

...not knowing, if this would affect the expression.

The only way for me is to comment out the "deny all". And it works. Actually i have in mind, to extend the renewal script to stop the server, change the owncloud-conf, restart the server again, fetch the new certs, stop the server again, change the owncloud-conf back und restart the server...

But maybe its more simple. And i may learn something more about regex...

Does anyone have a tip for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console)` denies access to any URI beginning with `/.` such as `/.well-known`.

Firstly, do you have any files and directories in the root which begin with a period (other than `/.well-known`)?

---

One option is to make the regex more specific, for example:

```
location ~ ^/(?:\.ht|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console)
```

would deny access to any URI beginning with `/.ht`.

---

Another option is to make `location '/.well-known/acme-challenge'` take precedence by adding the `^~` modifier. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge
```

This would make the location take precedence over **all** regex locations. So if the location contained `.php` files, they *may* cease to work.

---

A final option would be to turn it into a regex location:

```
location ~ ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge
```

In which case it would have equal precedence and you could order it above the deny location.

Comment: "location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge" solved it for. Also I did not try the other solutions. Thank you very much for your help. The documentation helped me as well to understand the regular expressions a little more and how nginx priorises the location-blocks.